# Java how to use pattern matcher using regular expressions to find certain string

Tags: java, regex

I am not familiar with Patterns & matchers, and I am pretty stuck with this problem.

I have a string that I would like to manipulate in Java.
I understand that I have to use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(in);

while(m.find()) {
     String found = m.group(1).toString();
}
```

But in my string, let's say I have the following examples:

```
String in = "test anything goes here [A#1234|567]"; //OR
String in = "test anything goes here [B#1234|567]"; //OR
String in = "test anything goes here [C#1234|567]";
```

I want to find `[A# | ]` or `[B# | ]` or `[C# | ]` in the string, how do I use the regex to find the expression?

Comment: do you want to find that `|` also, along with spaces?

Comment: Unclear if you want the numbers after A#, etc

Comment: It seems you want to replace "[0-9]+" to "". :)

Comment: Regex you are using will find these values for you. What exactly is problem you are facing?

Comment: @Ryven, yes, but the numbers should be "dynamic". I can have things like [A#656464566|874834637647], numbers can vary.

Comment: Examples of the desired matches would be helpful. E.g. I guess he wants to home in on A# and then get the numbers before and after the |.

Comment: @Pshemo, if I use regex="\\[(.*?)\\]", If I have [YYYIWGEGDB#8746736|836347], won't this be true in while(m.find()) as well? That is what I do not want...

Comment: @progricebowl Thank you. That was part I was interested in. So in other words you want to find **only** strings like `[A# | ]` or `[B# | ]` or `[C# | ]`. From your examples I see that before and after `|` you are using digits. Are only they allowed or is something like `[A#x|x]` also correct match? If not then take a look at Sabuj or Mena answer. Also are `A` `B` and `C` only characters you accept? What about something like `[D# | ]`

Comment: Check out my solution mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[ABC]#` in your regex to match your expression.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\[[ABC]#.*?\\])");
```

If the fields are digit then you can safely use `\d+`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\[[ABC]#\\d+\\|\\d+\\])");
```

Comment: How about the "|"? That would need to be present too... Is it possible to get that in?

Comment: @progricebowl I already updated the answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a simple `Pattern` as in the following example:

```
String[] in = { "test anything goes here [A#1234|567]",
            "test anything goes here [B#1234|567]",
            "test anything goes here [C#1234|567]" };

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[[A-Z]#\\d+\\|\\d+\\]");
    for (String s: in) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found: " + m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Found: [A#1234|567]
Found: [B#1234|567]
Found: [C#1234|567]
```

I'm assuming here that your `Pattern` has specific restrictions:

- Starts with `[`
- Followed by **one** upper-case non-accented letter
- Followed by `#`
- Followed by any number of digits
- Followed by `|`
- Followed by any number of digits
- Followed by `]`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\[[A-Z]#.*\\])");`

If you want to match any capital A through Z. Unclear if you want all the data between `[]` though.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Some {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        String[] in = {
            "test anything goes here [A#1234|567]",
                "test anything goes here [B#1234|567]",
                "test anything goes here [C#1234|567]"
        };

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
        for (String s: in ) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
            while (m.find()) {
                System.out.println("Found: " + m.group().replaceAll("\\d", ""));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This uses your original regex.

Demo: <kbd>http://ideone.com/4Z5oYD</kbd>